# Как найти num в данном случае, чтобы в конце она имела тип int?

Tags: java

Как найти **num** в данном случае, чтобы в конце она имела тип int?

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Decode {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 143;
        BigInteger num = BigInteger.valueOf((long)Math.pow(42, 103));
        num = num % n;
        num = (int)num;
    }
}
```

пробовал с long, но он не подошел к таким большим числам:

```
int n = 143;
long num = (long)Math.pow(42, 103);
System.out.println(num); // 9223372036854775807 long не достаточно
num = num % n;
num = (int)num;
```

Comment: Это возможно сделать?

Comment: Что значит «в конце»?

Comment: @ Артём Оконечников после всех преобразований(возведения в степень, %) сделать переменную num типа int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Math.pow` возвращает `double`. Числа с плавающей запятой могут представить гораздо большее значение, чем целочисленное. Получить из `double` `int` без усечения не получится. Зато получится сразу получить `BigInteger`:

```
BigInteger base = new BigInteger("42");
BigInteger result = base.pow(103);

System.out.println(result);
```

*После уточнения вопроса:*

```
BigInteger n = new BigInteger("143");
BigInteger num = new BigInteger("42");
BigInteger pow = num.pow(103);
BigInteger mod = pow.mod(n);

System.out.println(mod); // Можно mod.intValue()
```

Comment: а как потом сделать операцию % над result? получается нужно сделать result % n

Comment: @SwingForever [mod](https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/12.2.php)

Comment: @SwingForever обновил под задачу

Comment: спасибо большое, что то сложновато после питона на джаве писать)) спасибо

Comment: а как принять переменную типа int вместо 143 ---> new BigInteger("143")?

Comment: @SwingForever в яве, по соглашению, методы преобразования называются `valueOf`. В нашем случае `BigInteger.valueOf(x)`

Answer (score 2):

```
int intNum = new BigInteger("42").pow(103).remainder(new BigInteger("143")).intValue();
```

Comment: Да, странную роль сыграла эта часть: BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.pow(42, 103)).toBigInteger(). Исправил. Теперь 3.

Comment: @ pazukdev  спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Почему `42^103` не помещается в `long`? `long` может представлять числа до `2^63`, а наша степень требует `log2(42^103) = log2(42) * 103 > 555` бит.

В `double` `42^103` помещается. Но `double` точно представляет только `53` **старших** бита числа. Остальные 502 бит отброшены. А когда спрашивают про остаток от деления, то спрашивают в каком-то смысле про младшие биты. А они-то и отброшены.

Вариант с `BigInteger` решает задачу точно. Но задачу можно решить быстрее и без `BigInteger`.

Последнее действие в решении - взятие остатка по модулю. Правило умножения по модулю позволяет умножать не сами числа а их остатки:

```
(a * b) mod m = ((a mod m) * (b mod m)) mod m
```

Тогда цикл возведения в степень из

```
int pow = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < p; ++i) {
    pow *= b;
}
```

превращается в

```
int pow = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < p; ++i) {
    pow = (pow * b) % m;
}
```

Кажется что всё только усложнилось, но теперь нам не грозит переполнение. А так как мы умножаем "короткие" целые (`int`) а не "длинные" ('BigInteger`), то все работает намного быстрее.

Вариант с `BigInteger`:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Decode1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigInteger m = new BigInteger(args[0]);
        BigInteger b = new BigInteger(args[1]);
        int p = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

        System.out.println(b.pow(p).mod(m));
    }
}
```

Вариант с `int` и умножением по модулю:

```
public class Decode2 {
    public static int pow(int m, int b, int p) {
        int pow = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < p; ++i) {
            pow = (pow * b) % m;
        }
        return pow;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int m = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        int p = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

        System.out.println(pow(m, b, p));
    }
}
```

Сравним времена вычислений. `Decode1` замедляется сильнее всего. `Decode2` работает за время пропорциональное степени.

> ```
>      power  Decode1  Decode2  Decode3
>        103   0.054    0.050    0.059
>       1000   0.055    0.053    0.052
>      10000   0.070    0.051    0.048
>     100000   0.124    0.063    0.050
>    1000000   0.679    0.060    0.058
>   10000000  12.160    0.138    0.049
>  100000000   ?        0.914    0.052
> 1000000000   ?        8.795    0.050
> ```

`Decode3` реализует [быстрое возведение в степень по модулю](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8E#%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8E). Эта программа работает так быстро, что время в таблице - это время загрузки программы, а исполняется она за время, которое трудно измерить:

```
public class Decode3 {
    public static int pow(int m, int b, int p) {
        int pow = 1;
        for (; p > 0; p /= 2) {
            if (p % 2 == 1) {
                pow = (pow * b) % m;
            }
            b = (b * b) % m;
        }
        return pow;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int m = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        int p = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

        System.out.println(pow(m, b, p));
    }
}
```